# How to access a class method in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am prefacing this:
I am new to CoffeeScript and JavaScript prototyping as a whole.

That being said, I am trying to create a new Object of a class in CoffeeScript, and then call a getter to retrieve the variable but what happens is I get an 'undefined' response instead.  What am I doing wrong, or how I should I approach this.  I am fairly new and trying to follow the KISS standard.

```
class TestHandler
  constructor: ->
  testArray = []
  getTestArray: ->
    @testArray

tH = new TestHandler()
tH.testArray.push 1 #testArray returns undefined
tH.getTestArray().push 1 #getTestArray returns undefined
console.log tH.getTestArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a class in CoffeeScript every metod you list down there goes to the `prototype` property (in this case `TestHandler.prototype`) and therefore is shared among instances of that class, however every other property, will be either a member of `TestHandler` itself (if name prepended with `@`) or a private variable of scoped to a function that `class` will eventually be compiled to (like was with your `testArray = []`). It means, that your `tH` won't have a property called `testArray`. If you wanted it to be an own property of the each instance, put this into the constructor:

```
class TestHandler
    constructor: ->
        @testArray = []
    getTestArray: ->
        @testArray

tH = new TestHandler()
tH.testArray.push 1 #now everything works
tH.getTestArray().push 1
console.log tH.getTestArray()
```

---

Generally, where the property will land depends on how you write in the `class` declaration. Look at this CS code

```
 class TestHandler
   constructor: ->
     @testArray = [] #1
   testArray = [] #2
   @testArray = [] #3
   getTestArray: -> #4
   testArray: [] #5
```

and the code that it compiles to:

```
 var TestHandler;

 TestHandler = (function() {
   var testArray;

   function TestHandler() {
     #1 @thisArray in constructor becomes instance property accessor
     this.testArray = [];
   }

   #2 becomes a local variable, not available outside this function
   testArray = [];

   #3 becomes a "static" property
   TestHandler.testArray = [];

   #4 is a method that goes to the prototype, so that it can be shared with all instances
   TestHandler.prototype.getTestArray = function() {};

   #5 is a property that goes to the prototype and can be shared with all instances (although this shouldn't be done unless you know what you do)
   TestHandler.prototype.testArray = [];

   return TestHandler;

 })();
```

Comment: So to verify, everything outside of the constructor is pseudo-static, but those static objects can access the dynamic objects inside the class?

Comment: Not exactly. All depends on how you write it. With `@` inside `constructor` -> own property of instance (like I did with `@testArray` inside the `constructor`). With `@` inside the class -> static member. `name: ->` inside the class -> shared method. `name = value` inside class -> private variable, scoped to a function that class will compile to.

Comment: I'll update my answer to contain what I wrote in this comment, so that this would be clear.

Comment: After looking at your updated code, should I place all my class methods such as getters inside my constructor then?

Comment: Method that are shared to instances are invoked in their context. It means that if you do `tH.getTestArray()` method `TestHandler.prototype.getTestArray` will be invoked as it was a method of `tH`, therefore will have access to its properties (`this` inside it will point to `tH`). I would suggest reading some papers on how JavaScript inheritance works, for example [here](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype)